# How to set condition in shoping cart rule for cenario given below:

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

We have tops and bottoms of 15 "types". 15 tops and 15 bottoms, we want to give 20% discount only when abc top and abc bottom are in cart. Similarly if abc top, abc bottom and xyz top and xyz bottom are there they all should get 20%. If there's only top or only bottom, then no discount should apply.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please follow Below steps:

Step1: Add condition by selecting "Product Attribute Combination" and then select condition as If an item is FOUND  in the cart with **ANY**  of these conditions true

Step2: then add the sub condition by selecting product attribute like **Sku** and then put the tops and bottom skus combination as "Sku  is  x,y"

Step2: Repeat the step 2 for each combination.